# MS Access concurrent users

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I just have a quick question on MS Access Concurrency. I have built an input sheet in excel and the VB code opens a connection to a MS Access database logs 8 fields in about 5 milliseconds and closes the connection right away (for that particular user). I realize that Access has its limitations with concurrency, but what I really want to know if this is okay for 70 users? Not all of them will be logging data at the exact same time, if that would happen, I would say like 20-30 out of the 70 (the most) might log something at the exact same time.

On another note, the Access Database is only used for storing data, nothing else.

```
    Dim NewCon As ADODB.Connection
    Set NewCon = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim Recordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Set Recordset = New ADODB.Recordset

    NewCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\my.user\Desktop\Testing\Database1.accdb"
    Recordset.Open "DATA", NewCon, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
    Recordset.AddNew
    'Primary Key
    Recordset.Fields(0).Value = G
    'Field 2
    Recordset.Fields(1).Value = A
    'Field 3
    Recordset.Fields(2).Value = B
    'Field 4
    Recordset.Fields(3).Value = C
    'Field 5
    Recordset.Fields(4).Value = D
    'Field 6
    Recordset.Fields(5).Value = E
    'Field 7
    Recordset.Fields(6).Value = F
    'Field 8
    Recordset.Fields(7).Value = Format(Now, "m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss")


    Recordset.Update
    Recordset.Close
    NewCon.Close
```

Comment: Do you have the ability to use SharePoint lists, linking them with Access? If so, I would do that.

Comment: Should not be an issue.

Comment: Since you're only adding records, concurrency is not an issue at all. There is no chance of conflicting updates.

Comment: Thanks all, I've tested it out and works well.

Answer (score 1):

It should not be an issue. Or catch an error and try again.

If you experience serious trouble, you can use the method described here:

[Handle concurrent update conflicts in Access silently](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/25780/Handle-concurrent-update-conflicts-in-Access-silently.html)

which includes a full demo and code:

```
' Function to replace the Edit method of a DAO.Recordset.
' To be used followed by GetUpdate to automatically handle
' concurrent updates.
'
' 2016-02-06. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Sub SetEdit(ByRef rs As DAO.Recordset)

    On Error GoTo Err_SetEdit

    ' Attempt to set rs into edit mode.
    Do While rs.EditMode <> dbEditInProgress
        rs.Edit
        If rs.EditMode = dbEditInProgress Then
            ' rs is ready for edit.
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

Exit_SetEdit:
    Exit Sub

Err_SetEdit:
    If DebugMode Then Debug.Print "    Edit", Timer, Err.Description
    If Err.Number = 3197 Then
        ' Concurrent edit.
        ' Continue in the loop.
        ' Will normally happen ONCE only for each call of SetEdit.
        Resume Next
    Else
        ' Other error, like deleted record.
        ' Pass error handling to the calling procedure.
        Resume Exit_SetEdit
    End If

End Sub
```

and:

```
' Function to replace the Update method of a DAO.Recordset.
' To be used following SetEdit to automatically handle
' concurrent updates.
'
' 2016-01-31. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function GetUpdate(ByRef rs As DAO.Recordset) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo Err_GetUpdate

    ' Attempt to update rs and terminate edit mode.
    rs.Update

    GetUpdate = True

Exit_GetUpdate:
    Exit Function

Err_GetUpdate:
    If DebugMode Then Debug.Print "    Update", Timer, Err.Description
    ' Update failed.
    ' Cancel and return False.
    rs.CancelUpdate
    Resume Exit_GetUpdate

End Function
```

Also at [GitHub](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ConcurrencyUpdates.git)